# checking for modifications issues

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

I got a doubt regarding the usage of ccnet with clear case.I just
got an access to my clear case,i am facing another problem.I have a
VOB named Test_proj which contains many folders which are not of my
concern.Inside that particular VOB,i had made a test folder named
'MY_Source',where i had put all my source files.So when i ran the
ccnet,i found that its checking for mdifications for all the folders
which is really not needed.I just need my ccnet to check for
modifications in that particular folder which is MY_Source.So is there
any other tag which i need to mention along with the viewpath which
just checks for modfication in the particular folder in the VOB rather
than the whole VOB.

2.If it finds any modifications,it should also download the whole
source files and start the compilation process.So how can this be
configured in ccnet.

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample config. block I use for ClearCase:

```
<sourcecontrol type="clearCase">
  <viewPath>Y:\Mobi-Info\Source\Components</viewPath>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <useLabel>false</useLabel>
  <branch>main</branch>
</sourcecontrol>
```

`viewPath` specifies the root directory inside your ClearCase view which you want to be checked for modifications (in my case the **Components** directory). So if you want CCNet to react only to your **MY_Source** directory modifications, point directly to it in the `viewPath`.